# How do I change the XCode build location to Legacy using the console?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode6

Ok, so I know how to change XCode build setting to Legacy using the UI shown below.[image]

But how do I build an app from the console using that Legacy setting? I think it has something to do with the command `xcodebuild -derivedDataPath <path>`. But how do I set it to legacy?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Legacy` setting from `xcodebuild`, although you could use `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` to change the default build path:

```
xcodebuild -project 'MyProject.xcodeproj' \
           -configuration 'Release' \
           -sdk macosx10.10 CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Path/To/Build/Release
```

If you wanted to build a `Debug` version just change the `configuration` flag. If the path is a nonexistent directory `xcodebuild` should create it automatically.

Comment: the problem is that it is a workspace containing multiple older projects of different settings. The Legacy setting seems to let each workspace within the project use its own defined locations. I dont think the `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` alone will be enough. Is there no other way to make xcodebuild use something similar to legacy?